# Can't Sign-in Google account Login failed

Tags: java, api, android-studio, google-signin

I have created Google and Facebook login in my app But I can't Login in through my Google Account it shows `SignIn failed`.

I have seen the code it doe not show error the app alsso doe not get crash but I can't login through Google.I tried many different account of google but everytime it shows "SIGNIN FAILED".

```
    private void signIn() {
    if (checkPermission()) {
        if (UtilityMethods.isInternetAvailable(mContext)) {
            new GetQuestionOfTheDay(mContext).execute();
            new GetQuickTen(mContext).execute();
            loginType = "Google";
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } else {
            UtilityMethods
                    .showAlert(mContext, "No Internet Connection", 
   "Please enable internet connection to login.",
                               "Ok");
        }
    } else {
        requestPermission(ChoiceActivity.this);
    }
 }

 private void fbSignIn() {
    if (checkPermission()) {
        if (UtilityMethods.isInternetAvailable(mContext)) {
            new GetQuestionOfTheDay(mContext).execute();
            new GetQuickTen(mContext).execute();
            loginType = "Facebook";
            loginButton.performClick();
        } else {
            UtilityMethods
                    .showAlert(mContext, "No Internet Connection", 
 "Please enable internet connection to login.",
                               "Ok");
        }
    } else {
        requestPermission(ChoiceActivity.this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
   data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from 
 GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need 
to attach a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
   GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
 }

  private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> 
   completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = 
     completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        displayName = account.getDisplayName();
        socialMailId = account.getEmail();
        new Registration().execute();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure 
    reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference 
   for more information.
        AppUtil.log(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode(), 
   e);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SignIn Failed ...", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        databaseHandler.flushQuickTenData();
        // updateUI(null);
    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
 String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean isReadExternalStoragePermission = grantResults[0] 
  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean isWriteExternalStoragePermission = 
  grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (isReadExternalStoragePermission && 
 isWriteExternalStoragePermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChoiceActivity.this, "All Permission 
    Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isAccess = true;
                } else {
                    isAccess = false;
                    int i = 0;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    if (isReadExternalStoragePermission && 
    isWriteExternalStoragePermission) {
                        if (i == 1) {
                            stringBuilder.append(", Storage");
                        } else {
                            stringBuilder.append("Storage");
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ChoiceActivity.this, 
    stringBuilder.toString() + " Permission Denied",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
     }
 }
```

I tried Debug the app so when I press the account button in google it shows this error in my DEBUGGER.

```
 E/ChoiceActivity: signInResult:failed code=10
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:       at 
 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus
 (UnknownSource) at 
 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.
 getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
    at com.taxsmart.activity.ChoiceActivity.onActivityResult
    (ChoiceActivity.java:284)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6461)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults
    (ActivityThread.java:3960)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult
    (ActivityThread.java:4007)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
   (ActivityThread.java:1551)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
    (ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)"
```

Comment: Looking [at doc:][1]

>`public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR`

>The application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as fatal. The developer should look at the logs after this to determine more actionable information.

>`Constant Value: 10`

**It can be a problem of SHA1 mismatch.**

  [1]: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#DEVELOPER_ERROR

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you say what to do exactly in this I didn't quiet get you.If possible can you show me the code where I need to change and what to change.

Comment: It doesn't seem a problem in the code, but in the configuration in the google console panel. Check if you are using the same SHA1 key to sign the app and to configure the auth in the API.